# Advanced Logic Survey

Tags: infopath, survey

I trying to create a survey, but I want to be a little more intelligent about how it works.

For example, I will ask the users "Choose from this list of 30 things what is most important to you" then the next question will take those choices, put them into a new question and says "Now pick 3 that are the most important."

I'm a frequent user of SharePoint and have been investigating branching. But what i need is to branch to a question, and that questions answers are made up of the previous questions answers.

Maybe an infopath form could do this, however I am no expert in infopath. If someone could set me off on the right track I am willing to learn.

So like branching, their answer takes them to a different question. But the answers to that question are made up of their previous answers.

I could write something like this from scratch, but i'm looking for is an off the shelf tool I can use to do this? Like SharePoint.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What I'm looking for is like the vote for policies survey at this link: https://voteforpolicies.org.uk/ Its takes your choices as you go through and then feeds them back to you.

Comment: LimeSurvey http://www.limesurvey.org can do this